# Don't understand a step in the proof of Lemma 7.4 of Milnor's "Singular points of complex hypersurface"

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I am struggling to understand a step in Milnor's proof of the following lemma 7.4

[image]

The step I am stuck on is the following:
[image]

Why $v_t$ maps $M$ into itself ? 
In the proof he never uses the third hypothesis , so I think we have to use that hypothesis here.Please explain this.

Reference : Milnor's book on "Singular points of complex hypersurfaces" , lemma 7.4 , page 61.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the next line of the book, it only makes this claim "for small values of $t$". This follows from the fact that $v_0$ maps $M$ to itself and that $v_t$ is continuous in $t$.

Comment: I think only problem occurs when $x$ is in the boundary of $M$ , then $v(x)$ can lie outside $M$ and then $v_t(x)$ doesn't lie in $M$ .But because of the third hypothesis  $v(x)$ should lie in the interior of $M$ when $x$ is in the boundary.